# Classifying groups of order 399 and finding their centers and commutator subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $399=3\cdot 7 \cdot 19$. By Sylow Theorems, we get that there is a unique Sylow 19-subgroup. If $N$ is that subgroup and $H$ is a Sylow 7-subgroup, it's easy to show $NH$ is normal in $G$. We must examine $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_3 \to Aut(NH) \cong \mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}$. Let $\mathbb{Z}_3 = \langle s \rangle$, $N = \langle a \rangle$, and $H= \langle b \rangle$. Let $\varphi(s) = \sigma$. We must examine $\sigma(a,b)$ of order 3.

We know that $\sigma(a,b) = (a^k, b^l)$ such that $k^3 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ and $l^3\equiv  1 \mod 19$. If $k=l=1$, then $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_7\times\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ and has obvious center/commutator subgroup. If $k,l \ne 1$ , after some work, one determines that $k=2,3$ and $l=7, 11$. This gives a total of 9 groups of order 399.

At this point, they each have their own presentation, but how does one then determine the center? Simply messing around with the relations? Also, I found a document that gives the number of groups of order $n\le 2015$, and it says there only 5 groups of order 399. Any hints on how to determine which of mine are isomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

You found nine ways to map $\Bbb Z_3\to \operatorname{Aut}(NH)$. However, any two such homomorphism that differ only by an automorphims of $\Bbb Z_3$ lead to isomorphic groups. Thus instead of $1+8=9$ you get $1+\frac 82=5$.

Comment: In agreement with the table at http://orion.math.iastate.edu/maddux/504-Fall-2009/groups.pdf